# display number as text in export excel using poi

Tags: apache-poi

I write java program export excel using apache poi 
set cell value 00400 but it automatically convert 400 how can set value as 00400

cell type is set to String but cursor is enter to cell it also change to 400

Answer (score 1):

You do this exactly the same way you do in Excel itself - enter the number `400` then apply cell formatting to force it to have the leading zeros

As [covered in the Apache POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats), you'd do something like:

```
// Do this once
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("format sheet");
DataFormat format = wb.createDataFormat();

// Styles are per-workbook not per-cell
CellStyle style5Zeros = wb.createCellStyle();
style5Zeros.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("00000"));

// Create a cell and style
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(400);
cell.setCellStyle(style5Zeros);
```